# Failed to run query: error: 1023 on Redshift

Tags: concurrency, aws, redshift

I have a lambda :

```
'use strict';
const config = require('./redshift_config');
const pg = require('pg');
const redshift_conn = `pg://${config.user}:${config.password}@${config.host}/${config.database}`;

function move_to_disable_tables(users_ids, context) {
  const client = new pg.Client(redshift_conn);
  const query = `
  INSERT INTO disable_connections
  SELECT *
  FROM active_connections
  WHERE user_id
     IN (${users_ids});
  DELETE FROM active_connections
  WHERE user_id
     IN (${users_ids});
  INSERT INTO disable_downloads
  SELECT *
  FROM active_downloads
  WHERE user_id
     IN (${users_ids});
  DELETE FROM active_downloads
  WHERE user_id
     IN (${users_ids});
  `;

  client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return context.fail(`Failed to connect: ${err}`);
    }
    client.query(query, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return context.fail(`Failed to run query: ${err}`);
      }
      context.succeed(`Successfully transferred.`);
      client.end(function (err) {
        if (err) return context.fail(`Error in ending query: ${err}`);
      });
    });
  });
}

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  move_to_disable_tables(event.users_ids, context);
};
```

But I get sometimes :
"Failed to run query: error: 1023"

> The error you are getting occurs whenever you run concurrent transactions is such a way that Redshift's serializable isolation is violated. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html for a description of what this means.

From : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=443644#443644

Before the sql was warped into a block
`BEGIN; END;`
but I removed it to fix the issue but it still occurs. Any ideas?

Does this 4 queries can fail in concurrency?

The lambda doesn't run very often :

[image: screenshot]